# How to remove the shadow effect after button clicked in theme roller

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I know this could be a silly question. I have been trying to remove the shadow which comes after clicking any button in **ThemeRoller** for a while. There is no option given in the data theme roller to change the color or remove it.

Can anyone help me with that.

Thanks

**Edit 1**
Okay after dwelling into the css this is what worked for me

```
/* Focus buttons and text inputs with div wrap */
.ui-page-theme-c .ui-focus,
html .ui-bar-c .ui-focus,
html .ui-body-c .ui-focus,
html body .ui-group-theme-c .ui-focus,
html head + body .ui-btn-c.ui-focus,
html head + body .ui-body-c.ui-focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #3388cc /*{c-active-background-color}*/;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #3388cc /*{c-active-background-color}*/;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #3388cc /*{c-active-background-color}*/;
}
```

made the shadow to 0px instead of default 12px.

**Note:** you have to do it in the respective theme like mine was data-theme-c

Thanks to the people who shared there  answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after dwelling into the css this is what worked for me

```
/* Focus buttons and text inputs with div wrap */
.ui-page-theme-c .ui-focus,
html .ui-bar-c .ui-focus,
html .ui-body-c .ui-focus,
html body .ui-group-theme-c .ui-focus,
html head + body .ui-btn-c.ui-focus,
html head + body .ui-body-c.ui-focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #3388cc /*{c-active-background-color}*/;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0px #3388cc /*{c-active-background-color}*/;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #3388cc /*{c-active-background-color}*/;
}
```

made the shadow to 0px instead of default 12px.

Note: you have to do it in the respective theme like mine was data-theme-c

Thanks to the people who shared there answers

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try the following styles:

```
button:active{
box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

If the issue isnt related to box-shadow, try outline.

Comment: Its not working . I tried using outline also . What I am trying to change is the shadow effect which appears after clicking the button the default color is light blue I think